# iPad: problems with table rows in popovercontrol

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have an iPad application which implements the UISplitViewController. As usual I'm using the popover button to show the root view when the device is in portrait mode.
It's seems to be ok at time of launch, but if I turn the device to landscape, then back to portrait, the table in the popover, will have an additional blank row at top, so that I have to scroll down to see the others...
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an answer for this yet? I am having a similar problem but can't seem to figure out what is wrong.
The only difference I have is that I always have an extra row in the popup in portrait mode only. 
I am pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: Actually yes, but I can't tell you exactly what did the difference. If I remember well, when I wrote this question I used to code all the interfaces programmatically instead of using Interface Building, so my hint is: be lazy and let the stuff do the code for you. This solved the matter for me.