# UIPopoverController iOS 5.1 strange space when adding UINavigationController

Tags: ipad, ios5, uipopovercontroller

I have some UIPopoverController that were working fine in 4.3/5.0 iOS iPad.

Now, with iOS 5.1 I have a strange space on top.

You can see both images, in 4.3/5.0 the tableView is just below the navigationController.

In 5.1, there's a space, like a blank row, but it's not a row, you can't select, you can scroll but the blank is there.

The problem appear when I use a UINavigationController

```
MassMediaViewController * massMediaViewController = [[MassMediaViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:massMediaViewController];

UIPopoverController * popoverMassMedia = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];

[popoverMassMedia presentPopoverFromRect:textField.frame inView:self.scrollView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

[... release objects ...]
```

Any ideas of what's the problem ?

thanks,

[Related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336841/ipad-problems-with-table-rows-in-popovercontrol)

[image: iOS 4.3/5.0]
[image: iOS 5.1]

Comment: I've got the same problems for several days now and weren't able to find a solution. Seems as the TableView "thinks" the NavigationBar is in the space region. I tried a lot of things without any success. I'm very intereseted in a solution as well.

Comment: glad I'm not alone :-) If you push another view inside the popover and come back to first, the problem is gone, but this is not a workaround :-(

Comment: Any progress? Seems to be a bug, doesn't it. I might file a bugreport if you weren't able to find a solution as well!?

Comment: no, nothing yet :-( My Apps are most of them for InHouse so at this moment I force them to stay on 4.3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, I found the problem!

In the tableViewController's viewDidLoad I set the navigationBarStyle like this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

When you remove this line, everything works fine. Actually it doesn't do anything at all, because the barStyle is in that special popover style anyway. But because I'm using the same tableViewController for the iPhone, I set the barStyle.

I made another simple test project and was able to reproduce this bug and solve it by removing the barStyle setting.

I'll file a bugreport ...

Comment: you rock man!!!! Same problem here :-) Tested and removed and working fine ;-) thanks!